# .Net RIA Services missing datacontext

Tags: wcf-ria-services

After adding a domain service class, there are no datacontext classes for me to select from! What can I do to remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of Linq-to-Sql with RIA requires the WCF RIA Services Toolkit, it is not included by default.

The december 2010 version can be downloaded here:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=6f834bf7-ffde-4d5d-8573-18541762118b&displaylang=en